# How to use capybara against an external site without rails or rspec?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I want to use capybara to drive a web browser for an application I have written.  I don't want to run rspec tests, I want to use the browser to navigate and perform actions.  How do I set this up to use capybara command like 'visit' ?

I have:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara'
Capybara.default_driver  =:selenium
d= Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
d.navigate.to('http://www.google.com')
visit('http://www.google.com')
sleep 3
```

navigate.to works but visit gives me:

```
main.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `visit' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I've tried adding `include Capybara::DSL` but I get `uninitialized constant Capybara::DSL (NameError)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
Capybara.configure do |c| 
  c.run_server = false
  c.default_driver = :selenium
  c.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'
end
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

class RunIt
  include Capybara::DSL
  def runner
    visit '/' 
    sleep 1
  end
end

RunIt.new.runner
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, for taking time to share your knowledge..!